# exited, floating point exception

Tags: c, funciones, matrices, random, números-primos

soy nuevo en esto de la programacion , y estaba haciendo un programa en c , que genererá numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 100 y los guardara en una matriz de 8x8.
También quería que si esos numeros generados eran primos se quedaran en la matriz , en caso contrario guardas un 0.Al intentar compilar el programa me da el error del titulo , ¿alguien sabe que puede estar fallando?.Se que no es un codigo bonito , pero no se me ocurre otra manera de hacerlo.Tengo incluicas las librerias necesarias.
 ``

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>
  void rellenar(int m[8][8]);
  int primos(int a);

int main(){
  int m[8][8]; 
  rellenar(m);
  return 0;
}

void rellenar(int m[8][8]){
  int i,j;
  int num;
  srand("NULL");

   for(i=0;i<8;i++){
      for(j=0;j<8;j++){
          num=(rand() % 100)+1;
          m[i][j]=num;

           if(primos(num)==1){
               m[i][j]=num;
            }else{
               m[i][j]=0;
            }
         }
   }

     for(i=0;i<8;i++){
       for(j=0;j<8;j++){
          printf("%d\t",m[i][j]);
      }
       printf("\n");
  }

}
  int primos(int a){
    int i,cont=0;

     for(i=0;i<a;i++){
          if(a%i==0){
             cont++;
           }
       }

     if(cont==2){
        return 1;
        }else{
    return 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point exception ocurre cuando intentas hacer una operación cuyo resultado debería ser un número en coma flotante (un float) pero que es imposible de realizar para el procesador, por ejemplo un **división por cero**.

Míarte la línea donde tienes:

```
for(i=0;i<a;i++){
          if(a%i==0){
             cont++;
           }
       }
```